# Meteor not loading data

Tags: meteor

am calling my template like this `{{> list_items}}` and for some reason it doesn't work

this is the template code

```
<template name="list_items">
  {{#each items}}
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="{{previewImage}}" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4 class="pull-right">{{price}}</h4>
          <h4><a href="#">{{title}}</a></h4>
          <p>{{description}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

and `items` is a function in the template helper that returns the documents in my collection, here is its code:

```
Template.list_items.helpers({
  items: function(){
    return Items.find({});
  }
});
```

This is my Items collection allow rules

```
Items.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    // the user must be logged in, and the document must be owned by the user
    return true;
  },
  update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
    // can only change your own documents
    return true;
  },
  remove: function (userId, doc) {
    // can only remove your own documents
    return true;
  }
});
```

And collection inside "lib" folder so that i can use it from the client side.

When i tried to use Items.find().fetch() i get an empty collection `[]` Even though i have the collection with one document inside it

Why it doesn't work? are there any required package to be added first?

Comment: Do you have any documents in your `Items` collection? Are you publishing these from the server to the client _or_ do you have the _autopublish_ package installed? (New projects include it by default). Try typing `Items.find().fetch()` in your console and see what comes back.

Comment: @MichelFloyd i got an empty collection [], i removed autopublish and the collection is inside lib directory so that i can access it from the client side as well, and i did Items.allow rules, i modified my answer and included them

Comment: You need to publish the collection (from /server) and subscribe to that collection (/client). FYI - rules just tell Meteor what changes are possible from the client, they don't affect pub-sub.

Comment: @MichelFloyd yes now it is working, is it an addition to Meteor 1.3? i have almost the same code working without pub-sub, weird! Thanks anyway :)

Comment: This is the way it's always been in Meteor. You only avoid pub-sub if you autopublish.

Answer (score 1):

solved it by making publish and subscribe

in the server

```
Meteor.publish('items-all', function publishFunction() {
  return Items.find({});
})
```

in the client

```
Meteor.subscribe('items-all');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not allow you to find any data on client side.Items.find({}) will return empty docs.

```
Items.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    // the user must be logged in, and the document must be owned by the user
    return true;
  },
  update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
    // can only change your own documents
    return true;
  },
  remove: function (userId, doc) {
    // can only remove your own documents
    return true;
  }
});
```

If you want to allow Items.find({}) allow to all routes/templates. You can publish the data on server side like :

```
Meteor.publish('all-Items', function(){
  return Items.find({});
})
```

And on the client side you can subscribe the all-Items publish on inside the Meteor.startup like this :

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.subscribe('all-Items');
}
```

Then you can access Items.find({}) on each and every routes and that will return all the docs reactively.

Don't forget to add fetch function to see on console like : Items.find({}).fetch(), It will return array of your docs.